# Write serial number to file using Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to get the following Inno Setup code to work:

```pascal
[Setup]
UserInfoPage=yes

[Code]
function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := true;
  SaveStringToFile('c:\Registration.txt', Serial, False);
end;
```

The code is extremely simple when the file path is known at `UserInfoPage`. However it becomes extraordinarily complex when I need to write this file next to my application. Neither:

```pascal
WizardDirValue();
```

nor

```pascal
ExpandConstant('{app}');
```

do work. The first one is empty when called too early and the second one does not even run, I get:

> Internal error: an attempt was made to expand the "app" constant
> before it was initialized.

How does one store the `Serial` value to a file which needs to resides next to the application (.exe file) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand the [`{userinfoserial}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=userinfoserial) constant to get the serial number that the user entered in the info page in some event fired after the application directory is chosen, e.g.:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
UserInfoPage=yes
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
```

```pascal
[Code]
function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\Serial.txt'),
      ExpandConstant('{userinfoserial}'), False);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I personnally used `AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall` but that's equivalent. thx for the quick answer.

Comment: I'm using `AfterInstall` for *"file specific"* actions and I felt this more as a *"setup wide"* action, so I've used `CurStepChanged`, but it's a matter of taste. You're welcome!