# Load translation files to Pyqt5 application

Tags: python, pyqt5, inno-setup

I am developing a desktop application using Python 3.6 and PyQt5. After compiling the application using Pyinstaller i intend to make a setup file using Inno setup. The software give us the opportunity to choose the application's language while running the setup file. I would like to know how can i load the translation file (.qm file) based on that choice and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You know Inno setup always generates a script, use that script.

Inno setup has a Task, component, Run and Language options. You will only need Run and Language options for this.

The inno setup `{language}` constant returns the language selected by the user.

You should create a tiny cli that receives the language selected by the user from inno setup then set the language for your application either by creating a json file or database file.
Then your app reads the info from the json and loads .qm files accordingly.

Maybe you will call your tiny cli, setLanguage, in it receive the language which will be passed a parameter. So you may have something as:

```
import sys
import json

if (sys.argv) > 1:
    with open('settings.json', 'w') as fh:
        json.dump('{"language": "'+sys.argv[1]+'"}', fh)
```

Then in your Inno setup script, since the Run section executes in order, update it as follows:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\setLanguage.EXE"; Parameters: "{language}"
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

You can then read the json file from your app for the language the user selected

Now compile your app

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i don't think that's the answer to my question. What i want to do is to set the language of the application from the setup file built with the Inno setup software. I want to load the translation file based on that choice. I used to use menubar inside the app to load it but i now want to choose the application's language from setup.

Comment: Please @IkramRomdhani I have updated the answer

Comment: Your solution would work. But creating new CLI app for this task is an overkill. Inno Setup can create text files directly. See [Write serial to file using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25870729/850848).

Comment: Ok, @MartinPrikryl.